# Открытие разных ссылок на кнопку

Tags: java, android

помогите пожалуйста мне с реализацией данного метода:

есть приложение на java, в котором есть button.

Допустим есть:

sate1.com
sate2.com
sate3.com

При нажатии на кнопку у человека должен открываться sate1.com если нажмет еще раз, то sate2.com, если еще раз, то sate3.com и т.д. если ссылки закончились, то должно выводится сообщения, что ссылки закончились, как реализовать данные метод? Спасибо!

Я реализовал данный метод таким образом, ссылки открываются, но когда доходит до else происходит вылет приложения.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int index = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

    final ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("https://google.com/"));

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (index <= links.size()){
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(links.get(index)));
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
                // ссылки кончились
                !!тут у меня вылетает!!
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("Приходи завтра"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("TAG", "Конец.");

            }
            index++;

        }});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int index = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   final Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

   final ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("https://link.com/","https://link2.com/""https://link3.com/"));

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (index < links.size()){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(links.get(index)));
            startActivity(i);
        }else{
            // ссылки кончились
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("Приходи завтра"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("TAG", "Конец.");

        }
        index++;

    }});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Сделать это можно при помощи счетчика и массива ссылок. Делаем массив из ваших ссылок:

```
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

дальше объявим счетчик:

```
public int index = 0;
```

добавим обработку нажатий:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          links.get(index)
          index++;
          
     }});
```

предложенный выше вариант может выйти за пределы массива, поэтому добавим условие:

```
if (index <= links.size()){
links.get(index)
}else{
// ссылки кончились
}
```

и добавим это в нажатие кнопки:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              if (index <= links.size()){
                  links.get(index)
              }else{
                   // ссылки кончились
              }
              index++;
              
         }});
```

Comment: я реализовал данный метод, но ничего не происходит

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1165199/399126

Comment: Дополните ваш вопрос нажав на кнопку править

Comment: По коду насколько я вижу ничего и не происходит

Comment: Я использую android:onClick="startVideo". Я ваш код вставил в public void startVideo(View view) throws InterruptedException{...}. Почему ссылка не открывается, а на второй клик не выводится "Приходи завтра", приложение просто вылетает

Comment: Я привел код для обработки через нажатия на кнопку

Comment: Я сделал как у вас, посмотрите пожалуйста, я дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Я сделал чтобы ссылки открывались, но когда они кончаются приложение вылетает. помогите пожалуйста